Delay rendering of Mermaid Diagram in CEFSharp Browser
I am using CEFSHARP to create an embedded Browser in a C# WinForms application to display Mermaid diagrams by loading a local HTML file which contains the Mermaid syntax and the Java script
<script type="module">
        import mermaid from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@10/dist/mermaid.esm.min.mjs';
        const config = {
            startOnLoad: true,
            securityLevel: 'loose',
            theme: 'forest',
            sankey: {
                width: 800,
                height: 400,
                linkColor: 'source',
                nodeAlignment: 'justify',
                showValues: 'false',
            },
        };

        mermaid.initialize(config);

        await mermaid.run({
            suppressErrors: true,
        });
    </script>

The c# code is pretty simple:
Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());

Browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();

var HTML = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Mermaid.html"));
Browser.LoadHtml(HTML);

MainPanel.Controls.Add(Browser);
Browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

This all works but when the browser loads,the end users sees the raw mermaid script for a couple of seconds before the diagram is rendered. Is there any way of only displaying the diagram once it has been rendered, so the end user does not see the raw script text?
Thanks
